# Use interval to add on timestamp value from other table, in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm actually beginner in SQL and i working on Oracle engine. I have a problem to do arithmetic manipulation using Interval, to add on timestamp column - integer value, that exist in other table and convert it to Minute. 
To test my schemas i used in data generator. As a result, Some of the data produced, are not reliable and i need to check overlapping between two appointments, when the same patient invited for two treatments overlap.
I have treatments_appointments table that contains these attributes:

```
treatments_appointments(app_id         NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
   [fk] care_id        NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
   [fk]   doctor_id      NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
   [fk]   room_id        NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    [fk]  branch_id      NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    [fk]  patient_id     NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    appointment_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
```

Below is the code what i wrote and it's get an error message:

```
SELECT app1.app_id
FROM treatment_appointment app1
INNER JOIN treatment_appointment app2
ON app1.patient_id = app2.patient_id
WHERE app1.appointment_time >= app2.appointment_time  AND
app1.appointment_time <= 
app2.appointment_time + interval (to_char(select care_categories.care_duration where app2.care_id = care_categories.care_id)) minute
 AND
app1.app_id != app2.app_id
```

The error message is:
ORA-00936: missing expression
Sorry about my English and thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a fixed string value for [an `INTERVAL` literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements003.htm#i38598), not a variable, an expression or a column value. But you can use the [`NUMTODSINTERVAL` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions117.htm) to convert a number of minutes into an interval. Instead of:

```
interval (to_char(select care_categories.care_duration
  where app2.care_id = care_categories.care_id)) minute
```

Use:

```
numtodsinterval(select care_categories.care_duration
  where app2.care_id = care_categories.care_id, 'MINUTE')
```

Although you should join to that table in the main query rather than doing a subquery for every row:

```
SELECT app1.app_id
FROM treatment_appointment app1
INNER JOIN treatment_appointment app2
ON app1.patient_id = app2.patient_id
INNER JOIN care_categories cc
ON app2.care_id = cc.care_id
WHERE app1.appointment_time >= app2.appointment_time  AND
app1.appointment_time <= 
  app2.appointment_time + numtodsinterval(cc.care_duration, 'MINUTE') AND
app1.app_id != app2.app_id
```

Comment: Alternatively: `interval '1' minute * care_duration`